Go unit test using testcontainers on linux and WSL
I have some Golang unit tests which utilise testcontainers and the problem is that when run native on linux I get
Expected nil, but got: topology.ServerSelectionError{Desc:description.Topology{Servers:[]description.Server{description.Server{Addr:"localhost:32798"

creating mongodb container, when run on WSL on windows this is no issiue if
TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
is set. -> https://java.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/
If I add this option:
  HostConfigModifier: func(hc *container.HostConfig) {
    hc.NetworkMode = "host"
  },

inside
ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
  // ...
  HostConfigModifier: func(hc *container.HostConfig) {
  hc.NetworkMode = "host"
  },
  // ...
}

it works well on native linux as well but causes some issue on jenkins build machine.
Do you have any idea what should I do to fix this to unify this build process?
It seems that default docker's networkmode for linux is bridge and this is (or may be) source of problem.

If I understand correctly, you have a program in go that run on Windows and Linux and you encounter some issues when you try to test your program (When you run a MongoDB container). I think the issue could accrue because of the difference in Linux and window or WSL for this purpose,
the way WSL work is it translate the commends the Karnal get to Windows and throw them back at you, I recommend doing serial things:

add the option of giving more premtions to containers on Linux, for example c groups
differentiate between different OS, (Linux, mac, Windows, WSL)
try to work only on one OS for the time until everything work, then add support to other

